# trying to improve the efficency of a triple for loop in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize or make this loop run faster (it's a minimal code):

```
n=1000;
L=100;
x=linspace(-L/2,L/2);
V1=rand(n);
for i=1:length(x)
    for k=1:n
        for j=1:n
            V2(j,k)=V1(j,k)*log(2/L)*tan(pi/L*(x(i)+L/2)*j);
        end
    end
    V3(i,:)=sum(V2);
end
```

would appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a vectorized solution using `meshgrid`, `bsxfun` and `repmat`:

```
% fast preallocation
jj(n,n)=0; B(n,n,L)=0; V3(L,n)=0;
lg=log(2/L);

% the vectorizaion part
jj=meshgrid(1:n);
B=bsxfun(@times,ones(n),permute(x,[3 1 2]));
V3=squeeze(sum(lg*repmat(V1,1,1,numel(x)).*tan(bsxfun(@times,jj',pi/L*(B+L/2))),1)).';
```

Running your code at my computer using tic\toc took ~25 seconds. The bsxfun code took ~**4.5** seconds...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to vectorization, is to recognize the expensive operations in the code and somehow reduce them.  For instance, the `log(2/L)` is called 100*1000*1000 times with input that does not depend on any of the three `for` loops. If we calculate this value outside of the `for` loops, then we can use it instead:

```
logResult = log(2/L);
```

and

```
V2(j,k)=V1(j,k)*log(2/L)*tan(pi/L*(x(i)+L/2)*j);
```

becomes

```
V2(j,k)=(V1(j,k)*logResult*tan(pi/L*(x(i)+L/2)*j));
```

Likewise, the code calls the `tan` function the same 100*1000*1000 times.  Note how this calculation, `tan(pi/L*(x(i)+L/2)*j)` does not depend on `k`.  And so if we calculate these values outside of the `for` loops, we can reduce this calculation by 1000 times:

```
tanValues = zeros(lenx,n);
for i=1:lenx
    for j=1:n
        tanValues(i,j) = tan(pi/L*(x(i)+L/2)*j);
    end
end
```

and the calculation for `V2(j,k)` becomes

```
V2(j,k)=V1(j,k)*logResult*tanValues(i,j);
```

Also, memory can be pre-allocated to the `V2` and `V3` matrices to avoid the internal resizing that occurs on each iteration.  Just do the following outside the `for` loops

```
V2 = zeros(n,n);
V3 = zeros(lenx,n);
```

Using `tic` and `toc` reduces the original execution from ~14 seconds to ~6 on my workstation.  This is still three times **slower** than natan's solution which is ~2 seconds for me.